# Adding Label to Frame tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label, frame

I am trying to be able to display labels that are tied to a frame. I am unable to get either to show. There is something going on because packing or adding these changes the window size.

Main creates the main app, from which I create several frames that would belong to server objects. When servers are updated, they should reflect the change in the frames (and the labels attached to those frames) that are their respective attributes. However neither the frame nor labels display any text or color.

main.py

```
from settings.gui_settings import GLOBAL_FONT, SERVER_HEADER_COLUMN_FONT

from tkinter import *
from server import Server
from server_gui import ServerGui


SERVERS = []

# get_servers()
SERVERS = [
    Server(hostname='tyan-a320-1', ipv4='10.86.201.3', bmc_ipv4='10.86.203.88'),
    Server(hostname='tyan-a320-2', ipv4='10.86.201.91', bmc_ipv4='10.86.202.250'),
    Server(hostname='tyan-a320-3', ipv4='10.86.201.13', bmc_ipv4='10.86.201.2'),
    Server(hostname='tyan-a320-4', ipv4='10.86.201.50', bmc_ipv4='10.86.200.243'),
]

main_window = Tk()

for server in SERVERS:

    server.gui = ServerGui(main_window)

    server.gui.create_label('title', textvariable=server.hostname, font=(GLOBAL_FONT, SERVER_HEADER_COLUMN_FONT),\
                            bg='red', container=True)
    server.gui.labels['title'].pack()

    server.gui.pack()

    #server.update()

last_update_lbl = Label(master=main_window, text=f'Last Update: {time.ctime()}')
last_update_lbl.pack(side=TOP)

#main_window.update()
main_window.mainloop()
```

server.py

```
from settings.gui_settings import UP_COLOR, DOWN_COLOR
from diagnostics import poll
from diagnostics import ping
from diagnostics import SERVICES


class Server:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)

        self.services = {}
        for service in SERVICES:
            self.services[service] = None

    def update(self):

        address = None
        for service in self.services.keys():
            if 'bmc' in service:
                address = self.bmc_ipv4
            else:
                address = self.ipv4

            result = None
            if service == 'icmp':
                result = ping(address)
            else:
                result = poll(address, SERVICES[service])

            if result:
                self.services[service] = f'{service}: UP'
            else:
                self.services[service] = f'{service}: DOWN'
            if hasattr(self, 'gui'):
                self.gui.update_label(service, 'textvariable', self.services[service])
                self.gui.update_label(service, 'bg', UP_COLOR if 'UP' in self.services[service] else DOWN_COLOR)
                self.gui.master.update()
```

server_gui.py

```
from tkinter import Frame, Label, StringVar


class ServerGui(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.labels = {}

    def create_label(self, name, **kwargs):

        if not len(name):
            print("Label not named")
            exit(0)

        text = None
        label = Label(self)
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k == 'textvariable':
                text = StringVar(master=label, value=v)
                label.textvariable = text
            else:
                label.__setattr__(k, v)

        if 'bg' not in kwargs.keys():
            label.bg = LABEL_DEFAULT_COLOR

        if not text:
            text = StringVar(master=label, value=name)
        self.labels[name] = label
        self.labels[name].pack()
        print('Label %s created' % name)

    def update_label(self, name, attr, value):

        if name not in self.labels:

            self.create_label(name,
                              textvariable=StringVar(self, f'{name}'),
                              font=(GLOBAL_FONT, SERVER_INFO_FONT),
                              padx=10,
                              pady=10
                              )

            self.labels[name].pack()

        if attr == 'textvariable':
            self.labels[name].textvariable.set(value)
        else:
            setattr(self.labels[name], attr, value)
```

settings/gui_settings.py

```
MAIN_WINDOW_MIN_WIDTH = 700

GLOBAL_FONT = 'Tahoma'
SERVER_HEADER_COLUMN_FONT = 20
SERVER_INFO_FONT = 12

UP_COLOR = 'green'
DOWN_COLOR = 'red'

LABEL_DEFAULT_COLOR = 'green'
```

Comment: You are setting *attributes* of the label created, not *options*.  Use `label[k] = v` instead of `label.__setattr__(k, v)` inside `server_gui.py`.  Also *container* option is not a valid option for label.

Comment: @acw1668 Spot on.